# HTML Text after table

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to get text after a table in HTML but for some reason I cannot get this to work. I have tried using div, padding and margin on the table but nothing seem to work. No matter what I do the text always end up behind the first row of the table unless I use `</br>`.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div>
<h2 align=left>1. Delivery schedule</h2>
<body> The table below list the various delivery cycles per store:</body>
<br>
<br/>
<p>
<table border="1" align="left" width="61%" height="100px" frame="border">
  <tr>
    <th height="30" bgcolor="#002387">Store name</th>
    <th height="30" bgcolor="#002387">Order deadline</th>
    <th height="30" bgcolor="#002387">Delivery lead time from approval date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#002387" ><font color="#FFFFFF"> Cycle 1</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Borehamwood</td>
  <td>Friday 1st August 2014 by midday</td>
  <td>2-4 working days</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hemel</td>
    <td>Friday 1st August 2014 by midday</td>
    <td>2-4 working days</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<importantLink>Please note that the advertised 2-4 working days delivery lead time is conditional of the orders being approved by the regional operation managers by the end of order deadline day.</importantLink>
```

Comment: The code you provided [does not reproduce the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/uZuQK/), The link is aside the table since it's an inline element, it isn't behind anything as far as i can see. Try updating that fiddle to reproduce it.

Comment: And out of curiosity, where did you find the tag `<importantLink>`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually html elements go one after another unless you give an element a property such as `float:left` or `float:right` or in your case `align:left` so elements after the table won't be under that table, they will be positioned on it's right and from the top.

if you want that link to be after the table (under that table) remove the `align:left` from the table,

and when writing HTML make sure the opening and closing tags are the same and that your content is inside the body tag, here is the correction for that:

```
<html>    <!--<div>-->
<body>
    <h2 align=left>1. Delivery schedule</h2>
    <p> The table below list the various delivery cycles per store:</p>
    <br>
    <br/>
    <div><!--<p>-->
        <table border="1" align="left" width="61%" height="100px" frame="border">
        <tr>
                <th height="30" bgcolor="#002387">Store name</th>
                <th height="30" bgcolor="#002387">Order deadline</th>
                <th height="30" bgcolor="#002387">Delivery lead time from approval date</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#002387" ><font color="#FFFFFF"> Cycle 1</font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Borehamwood</td>
                <td>Friday 1st August 2014 by midday</td>
                <td>2-4 working days</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hemel</td>
                <td>Friday 1st August 2014 by midday</td>
                <td>2-4 working days</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <importantLink>Please note that the advertised 2-4 working days delivery lead time is conditional of the orders being approved by the regional operation managers by the end of order deadline day.</importantLink>
</body>
<html>
```

this line `<table border="1" align="left" width="61%" height="100px" frame="border">`
 is causing your issue, either remove `align:left` or change `<importantLink>` to `<importantLink style="clear:both">`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is bleeding from many wounds. First of all, you should forget about the `align` attribute, and use a CSS class instead.

```
.align-left {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```
<h2 class="align-left">1. Delivery schedule</h2>
```

Then, you have an unclosed `<p>` tag right before your table, which could be causing your problem. Having invalid markup can lead to unexpected results. And finally, `importantLink` - depending on your `<!DOCTYPE>` - is likely not valid *(you have a doctype, right?)*. Use a standard element like an `<a>` tag, which actually means that it's a link, and if you want to be able to tell it apart from the rest, use a `class` or `id` tag to give it a reusable/unique name, respectively. In your case, the text you are presenting in that tag is nothing like a link, so I suppose a `<p>` tag is the most suited for your case.

```
<p class="importantLink">Please note that the advertised 2-4 working days delivery lead time is conditional of the orders being approved by the regional operation managers by the end of order deadline day.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text within the `<importantLink>` to be displayed below the table you insert text in a div tag as below:

```
<div style="clear:both">
 <importantLink>Your text comes here....</importantLink>
</div>
```

Replace your importantLink with the three lines of code  above.